# Windows forms - calling the same function from different forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a little problem with windows forms in c#.
Let's keep it simple: I have a method which sets the default background color and foreground color. I have multiple forms from which I want to call it and I want have only one method (keep the possibility to add a default background image, etc... ). How should I do it ?

This is the basic code:

```
public void LoadGraphics() {
  this.BackColor = Graphics.GraphicsSettings.Default.BackgroundColor;
  this.ForeColor = Graphics.GraphicsSettings.Default.ForegroundColor;
  this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(Graphics.GraphicsResources.bg_small);
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code? In which class do you have written your code?

Comment: Hello, the code is in this style (this.BackColor = color;). The class that's currently one of the problems. If i write it in the form class, all work for the form, but i want make one code work in more forms.

Comment: Please add code into the question next time, not in comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a parent class that implements the method and derive your Forms from that parent class:

```
class Foo : Form {
    void LoadGraphics() {
        this.BackColor = Graphics.GraphicsSettings.Default.BackgroundColor;
        this.ForeColor = Graphics.GraphicsSettings.Default.ForegroundColor;
        this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(Graphics.GraphicsResources.bg_small);
    }
}

class YourForm : Foo {
    void someFunction() {
        LoadGraphics();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working perfectly. For the next time I will write the code directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a static class that contains the code to be shared between your forms:

```
static class Utils
{
    public static void ChangeColor(Form form, Color color)
    {
        form.BackColor = color;
    }
}
```

Then you can call this function from any other form:

```
Utils.ChangeColor(this, Color.Red);
```

Comment: This completely defeats all the possibilities and tools you have in object-oriented programming.